# Limitations of AsciiMath

Tags: asciimath

Is AsciiMath (asciimath.org) able to describe all current math notation, or is there math notation that it is unabled to describe? If so, what are some things that it cannot do.

Also, in the Grammar section of the website, I see a BNF grammar. Is the AsciiMath syntax a valid context free grammar?

I'm thinking about creating a compiler to read math notation in some type of text form and output an image from it, and AsciiMath seems like a good alternative to TeX. I'm just interested in describing math, visually, which AsciiMath focuses on, while TeX/LaTeX have more document layout stuff that I don't need.